# Add-in is not loading in office

Tags: com, ms-office, office-addins

I have a word com add-in that has been working fine previously but due to some reasons, I reinstalled my Windows-OS, MS-office and add-in software right after that It is showing in inactive add-in category. but the load behavior is "load at startup".

unable to find the exact reason. please help me and tell me how to debug this and know the root cause of this

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple reasons why add-ins are disabled by host applications...

First of all, I'd recommend checking all the required prerequsites on the target machine. Make sure that al of them were installed correctly before running the host application with your add-in registered.

Microsoft Office applications can disable VSTO Add-ins that behave unexpectedly. If an application does not load your VSTO Add-in, the application might have hard disabled or soft disabled your VSTO Add-in.

Hard disabling can occur when an VSTO Add-in causes the application to close unexpectedly. It might also occur on your development computer if you stop the debugger while the Startup event handler in your VSTO Add-in is executing.

Soft disabling can occur when a VSTO Add-in produces an error that does not cause the application to unexpectedly close. For example, an application might soft disable a VSTO Add-in if it throws an unhandled exception while the Startup event handler is executing.

When you re-enable a soft-disabled VSTO Add-in, the application immediately attempts to load the VSTO Add-in. If the problem that initially caused the application to soft disable the VSTO Add-in has not been fixed, the application will soft disable the VSTO Add-in again. Read more about that in the [How to: Re-enable a VSTO Add-in That Has Been Disabled](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms268871.aspx) article.

You may also find the following articles helpful:

- [Troubleshooting COM Add-In load failures](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsod/archive/2008/04/22/troubleshooting-com-add-in-load-failures.aspx)
- [Troubleshooting Run Time Errors in Office Solutions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/6s0wczt9(v=vs.100).aspx)